# How to disable the Junit results when executing the testng maven tests

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

we are using jenkins for running the selenium maven testng tests, we are using jenkins dashboard plugin to see the no. of tests passed and failed.

We have recently added the retry analyzer to execute the failed test twice, and the retried tests are correctly reported by testng as the skipped tests.

But after the implemntation of retry analyzer number of tests available on jenkins dashborad are going up and down because now we have alot of skipped tests on jenkins and that started causing issues with the other charts.

So we implemnted the logic to update the testng results file to autometically remove the skipped tests. This is giving te correct results.

But jenkin maven plugin does not consider the testng results, it is still reading the junit results file and producing the results with the skipped tests on the jenkins dashboard.

We have added another step to archive the testng results on jenkins job, but after that we are seeing multiple graphs inside the job execution results page and the dashboard page is still considering the junit results.

Now I have two questions

1) Is there a way to disable the generation of JUnit results inside maven testng tests.
2) Is there a way to force jenkins to use the testng results.

or if you have any other suggestions for resolving this issue, then please let me know.

Below is the jenkins job snapshot

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide details of the Jenkins Job configuration.

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: Instead of using the Maven Project  Job type in Jenkins create a  FreeStyle Project job. I think you can a full control, internally Maven Project Type linked with JUnits.

Comment: It worked, thanks !!